# controlling theorem numbers using llncs style

Tags: numbering, theorems, lncs

Is there a way to control the numbering of different types of theorems, when using the `llncs` style?

With the **envcountsame** parameter, all theorems/definitions/claims use the same counter and get sequential numbering. What I'd like to have is that *Theorems* / *Propositions* / *Lemmas* will use one counter, and *Definitions* will use a different counter (also *Remarks* should use a new counter, maybe the one of *Lemmas* maybe totally fresh one).

Suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define new theorem-like environments numbered as you like. If you want definitions to use their own counter, you can do

```
\spnewtheorem{defn}{Definition}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}
```

and this will do. You could also redefine the `definition` environment:

```
\documentclass[envcountsame]{llncs}

\let\definition\relax % undefine the environment
\spnewtheorem{definition}{Definition}{\bfseries}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
\begin{lemma}
Lemma
\end{lemma}
\begin{theorem}
Theorem
\end{theorem}
\begin{definition}
Definition
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

This might be even better, so you can revert to the usual class setting just by commenting the two lines.

[image]